# Is the last level cache shared by the sockets on a multiple socket machine?

Tags: caching, memory-management, operating-system

I am trying to understand the architecture of a multi-socket machine.
I read the LLC or the Last-level Ccahe is shared by all the cores in a multicore machine. Now if a machine supports multiple sockets will a single last level cache be shared by the multiple sockets or each socket has it's own LLC?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether "last-level cache" is a widely-used term.  I suspect that it is not.

References that I could find defined it as an on-chip cache used for SOC (System On Chip).

If that's the meaning that you're referencing, and if I'm correct to interpret "socket" in your question to mean the sockets that the chips are plugged into... then the answer would be "no".  On-chip cache would not be shared between different chips.

I think that you should look at the system architecture for some targets that you are interested in to answer the question.